# FindFirstFile keeps on running the same file when encryption

Tags: c++, windows, encryption, msdn

I am trying to encrypt all the files in a particular folder and that folder has sub folders when i try to print all the files it works good but when i try to encrypt all the files it keeps on encrypting the same file again and again

```
void dirListFiles(wchar_t *startDir) {
HANDLE hFind;
WIN32_FIND_DATA wfd;
wchar_t path[99999];
char *enName;
const char *extension = ".enc";
int wcsChars;

wsprintf(path, L"%s\\*", startDir);

if ((hFind = FindFirstFile(path, &wfd)) == INVALID_HANDLE_VALUE) {
    return;
}

do {
    if ((wcsncmp(L".", wfd.cFileName, 1) !=0) && (wcsncmp(L"..", wfd.cFileName, 2) != 0) ) {
        wsprintf(path, L"%s\\%s", startDir, wfd.cFileName);
        if (wfd.dwFileAttributes & FILE_ATTRIBUTE_DIRECTORY) {
            dirListFiles(path);
        } else {
            wcsChars = wcslen(path);
            char *szTo = new char[wcsChars + 1];
            szTo[wcsChars] = '\0';
            WideCharToMultiByte(CP_ACP, 0, path, -1, szTo, wcsChars, NULL, NULL);

            enName = (char *)malloc(strlen(szTo) + 1 + 4);
            strcpy(enName, szTo);
            strcat(enName, extension);
            // If i add this line it keeps on encrypting the same file
            //fencrypt(szTo, enName, (unsigned const char*)"1234567812345678");

            printf("%s\n", enName);

            delete[] szTo;
            free(enName);
        }
    }
} while(FindNextFile(hFind, &wfd));

if (GetLastError() != ERROR_NO_MORE_FILES) {
    FindClose(hFind);
    return;
}
}
```

If i add fencrypt(szTo, enName, (unsigned const char*)"1234567812345678"); then it encrypts the files in the main folder that is `G:\WinApp` but when it enters `G:\WinApp\ipch\winapp-1918e0a3` it keeps on encrypting the same file again and again there is no file in `G:\WinApp\ipch\` only a folder `winapp-1918e0a3` this is my encryption function please tell where am i wrong

```
void fencrypt(char* read, char* write, const unsigned char* enc_key) {
RAND_bytes(iv, AES_BLOCK_SIZE);

readFile = fopen(read,"rb");
writeFile = fopen(write,"wb");

fwrite(iv, 1, 8, writeFile);
fwrite("\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0", 1, 8, writeFile);

AES_set_encrypt_key(enc_key, 256, &key);

init_ctr(&state, iv);
while(1) {
    bytes_read = fread(indata, 1, AES_BLOCK_SIZE, readFile); 
    AES_ctr128_encrypt(indata, outdata, bytes_read, &key, state.ivec, state.ecount, &state.num);

    bytes_written = fwrite(outdata, 1, bytes_read, writeFile); 
    if (bytes_read < AES_BLOCK_SIZE) {
        break;
    }
}

fclose(writeFile);
fclose(readFile);
}
```

Comment: if I remember correctly, you have to call after the first call to "FindFirstFile" the function "FindNextFile" to get the other files

Comment: Sorry but i have called FindFirstFile before FindNextFile

Comment: that is correct, my bad i haven't seen it

Comment: Please, add punctuation... I suspect, that inside `../ipch` you keep on encrypting `../ipch/.` and system keeps recreating it.

Comment: @thebaconing - Np :)
@PetrBudnik - Sorry but in `../ipch/` there is only one file named `winapp-441daa35.ipch`

Comment: @KeshavNair If it were so, then why do you have `if ((wcsncmp(L".", wfd.cFileName, 1) !=0) && (wcsncmp(L"..", wfd.cFileName, 2) != 0) )` ;)?

Comment: @PetrBudnik - sorry but when i run FindFirstFile it shows me `.` and `..` with all the list of files in each directory so if it finds files named with `.` or `..` then it will skip those files and continue ;)

Comment: @KeshavNair That's what I'm saying - each directory (including sub-directories.) has `.` and `..` files. Even if there is no user files ;). Anyway, glad you solved it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm far from 100% sure, but I have a feeling that when you create a new file in your directory, the `FindNextFile` gets confused and finds the same filename again because it's not actually the same file. You may need to either collect a list of all files in a directory and process them one at a time, or keep a list of what you have already done and skip over the ones you have done.

Comment: ahh thanks :) you are correct that why it keeps on appending `.enc` again and again

Answer (score 0):

The `FindNextFile` call will probably see the newly appeared encrypted file and therefore you will keep processing the new files also.

Since you are appending an ".enc" extension to your encrypted files, it would be relatively simple to skip files that already have this extension.